# Find polynomials $P(x)P(x-3) = P(x^2)$

Tags: polynomials, solution-verification

> Find all polynomials  $P \in \Bbb R[x]$ such that $P(x)P(x-3) = P(x^2) \quad \forall x \in \Bbb R$

I have a solution but I'm not sure about that. Please check it for me.

It is easy to see that $P(x) = 0, P(x) = 1$ satisfied.

**Consider $P(x) \neq c$ :**

We have $P(x+3)P(x) = P((x+3)^2)$

If $a$ is a root of $P(x) $ then $a^2$ and $(a+3)^2$ are roots of $P(x)$.

If $|a| > 1$, then $ |a^2| = |a||a| > |a| \Rightarrow P(x)$ has infinitely many roots.

If $0 < |a| < 1$, then $|a^2| = |a||a| < |a| \Rightarrow P(x)$ has infinitely many roots.

If $a = 0 \Rightarrow (a+3)^2 = 9$ is a root of $P(x)$, so  $P(x)$ has infinitely many roots.

Hence, every root $a$ of $P(x)$ has $|a| = 1$. So $1 = |(a+3)^2| = (|a+3|^2) \Rightarrow |a+3|=1$.

We have $a + 3 = \cos\alpha + i\sin\alpha + 3 \Rightarrow (\cos\alpha+3)^2 + \sin^2\alpha = 1 \Rightarrow \cos\alpha = -\frac{3}{2}\ (\text{impossible}).$

$P(x) = 0, P(x) = 1$ are all the results.

Comment: Our you could refute $|a+3|=1$ with the triangle inequality.

Comment: Seems to be solved also on AoPS as found by [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24P(x)P(x-3)%20%3D%20P(x%5E2)%24&p=1)

Comment: @J.G. How to use the triangle ineuqality ?

Comment: @KiênPhùngHữu If $|a|=1$ then $|a+3|\ge|1-|3||=2$.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1677723/find-all-polynomials-p-such-that-px2-pxpx1

Answer (score 1):

Your  approach  is sound and the arguments besides  the last case $|a|=1$ are clear. Here  is  a slightly more stringent variant, which does not bring anything new, besides maybe the modified argument for the case $|a|=1$.

> We are looking for all polynomials $P\in\mathbb{R}[x]$ such that 
>   \begin{align*}
> P(x)P(x-3)=P(x^2)\qquad \forall x\in\mathbb{R}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

Proof:

> - **Constant  Polynomial $P$:** At first we look at polynomials $P(x)=c$ which are constant. From (1) we obtain
>     \begin{align*}
>   c^2&=c\\
>   c(c-1)&=0\tag{2}
>   \end{align*}
>     Since the equation (2) is solved iff  $c=0$ or $c=1$, these are the only solutions when $P$ is a constant polynomial.

In the following we consider all possible cases when $P$ has a root $a\in\mathbb{R}$. We divide the cases into

\begin{align*}
|a|>1,\qquad 0<|a|<1,\qquad a=0,\qquad a=-1\quad \text{and} \quad a=1
\end{align*}
which cover all possibilities.

> - **Root $P(a)=0$ with $|a|>1$**:
>
>   Let $a\in\mathbb{R}$ with $|a|>1$. We get from (1)
>     \begin{align*}
>   P(a^2)=P(a)P(a-3)=0\cdot P(a-3)=0\tag{3}
>   \end{align*}
>
>   From (3) we conclude that there is an infinite sequence $(a^{2n})_{n\geq 0}$ of pairwise different roots of $P$. Thus, $P$ has infinitely many roots and it follows $P$ is the zero-polynomial: $P=0$.

In the same way we can treat the next case.

> - **Root $P(a)=0$ with $0<|a|<1$**:
>
>   Let $a\in\mathbb{R}$ with $0<|a|<1$. We get from (1)
>     \begin{align*}
>   P(a^2)=P(a)P(a-3)=0\cdot P(a-3)=0\tag{4}
>   \end{align*}
>
>   From (4) we conclude as we did in the case before that there is an infinite sequence $(a^{2n})_{n\geq 0}$ of pairwise different roots of $P$. Thus, $P$ has infinitely many roots and it follows $P$ is the zero-polynomial: $P=0$.

Three more cases to follow:

> - **Root $a=0$:**
>
>   Let $a=0$ with $P(0)=0$. We get from (1) setting $x=3$
>
> \begin{align*}
> P(9)=P(3)P(0)=P(3)\cdot 0=0
> \end{align*}
>
> We see that $9$ is also a root of $P$. We are now in the case with root $|a|>1$ and conclude $P=0$.
>
> - **Root $a=-1$:**
>
>   Let $a=-1$ with $P(-1)=0$. We get from (1) setting $x=2$
>
> \begin{align*}
> P(4)=P(2)P(-1)=P(2)\cdot 0=0
> \end{align*}
>
> We see that $4$ is also a root of $P$. We are now in the case with root $|a|>1$ and conclude $P=0$.
>
> - **Root $a=1$:**
>
>   Let $a=1$ with $P(1)=0$. We get from (1) setting $x=4$
>
> \begin{align*}
> P(16)=P(4)P(1)=P(4)\cdot 0=0
> \end{align*}
>
> We see that $16$ is also a root of $P$. We are now in the case with root $|a|>1$ and conclude $P=0$.

**Conclusion:** We have covered all types of different polynomials which fulfill the relationship (1) and conclude that $\color{blue}{P=0}$ and $\color{blue}{P=1}$ are the only solutions of (1).$\qquad\qquad\qquad\Box$

*Note:* When making rigorous proofs we should avoid phrases like: *It is clear that ...*, *It is easy to see that ...*. It is much more preferable  to prove even seemingly simple things, just to be sure that we don't overlook anything.

Comment: What if P does not have *real* roots?

Comment: @user26857: Here we consider domain $\mathbb{R}$. The note addresses OPs formulation in the constant part section.

Comment: As far as I know there are real polynomials without real roots.

Comment: @user26857: Correct. But if we consider complex roots, which are not reals we would have to consider polynomials with domain $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: I can not see any reason for doing this. In fact, you talked about the roots of P, not about its coefficients.

Comment: @user26857: The functional equation  $P(x)P(x-3)=P(x^2)$ is stated to be valid for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. If we would have to consider complex polynomials, this is typically stated in the problem. In my answer I've restricted the roots $a$ under consideration as being roots in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The question is wrongly stated. Such problems show the confusion many people make between polynomials and polynomial functions. The correct statetment is to find the real polynomials $P$ with the property $P(X)P(X-3)=P(X^2)$ (where $X$ is an indeterminate). This entails us to give complex values to $X$.

Comment: Anyway, if $P(x)P(x-3)=P(x^2)$ for every $x\in\mathbb R$, then the polynomial $P(X)P(X-3)-P(X^2)$ is zero. Starting from here we can consider complex roots of $P$.

Answer (score 0):

Considering

$$
P(x)P(x-b)=P(x^2),\ \ \ b \ne 0\ \ \ \ (1)
$$

As long as $P(x^2)$ is even then $P(x)P(x-b)$ is also even then

$$
P(b)P(0) = P(b^2)
$$

because making $x = b$ in $(1)$ we have $P(b)P(0) = P(b^2)$, As this is for a generic $b$ we have $P(x)P(0) = P(x^2)$

or

$$
P(x)P(0) = P(x^2) = P(-x)P(-(x+b))
$$

which implies that $P(x)$ is even as well as $P(x+b)$

This should be true for all $b \ne 0$ so the solution is $P(x) = C_0$

Finally, according to $C_0^2=C_0$ we conclude that $C_0 = 0$ or $C_0 = 1$

Comment: I don't understand much from this answer. Is $b$ intended to replace $3$ in the original question? If yes, then why "this should be true for all $b\ne o$"? I also don't get how you derived $P(x)P(0)=P(x^2)$.

Comment: If $b\ne 0$ then $P(x) = \{0,1\  \}$ If $b = 0$ there are other solutions. I included an additional intermediary step.

Comment: In my opinion $b$ is fixed and you can't use it to derive $ P(x)P(0)=P(x^2)$.

Comment: I think that as long as the relationship comes from  a functional  identity, that should be true.

Comment: I don't think so.

Answer (score -1):

You point out that if $a$ is a root then $a^{2}$ is a root and $a+3$ is a root.

You don't need to divide into three cases to determine that means either infinitely or zero roots.

By induction  $a + 3k; k \in \mathbb N$ are roots.  If $j\ne k$ then $a+3j \ne a + 3k$ so if there is one root $a$ there are at least countably infinite *distinct* roots.  So there are either *zero* roots, of infinitely many roots.

Magnitude is irrelevant[1]

Only trivial constant polynomials have infinite or zero (complex) roots so that means $P(x) = c$ for some $c$ where $c^2 = P(x)P(x-3) =P(x^2) = c$.

[1]

Although if $a$ is a root then $a +3$ is a root.  And  if $|a+3| < 1$ then $|a+3| + |a|=|a+3| + |-a| \ge |(a+3)+(-a)| =|3|=3$ so $|a|\ge 3-|a+3| > 2$.  So at least one root is $\ge 1$.

Comment: Actually $(a+3)^2$ is a root.

Comment: Did I ever say it wasn't?

Comment: I don't know if you said it or not, but the OP surely didn't say that $a+3$ is a root provided that $a$ is a root.

Comment: Oh... you are right.   Well.... same thing.

Comment: So far, so good. But could you show that if $a$ is a root of $P$ then $a+3$ is also a root?